# confusion on the multiple thread

Tags: c, multithreading

I have a multiple threaded program, but I cannot understand it running result.

```
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>

void *test(void *args){
 int num = *(int*)args;
 printf("the value of num: %d at %p\n", num, args);
 pthread_exit("exit");
 return NULL;
}

int main ()   
{   
 int i, err;
 void * reStr;
 int THREAD_NUM = 2;
 pthread_t child[THREAD_NUM];
 for(i = 0; i < THREAD_NUM; i++) {
  printf("Creating thread %d at %p\n", i, &i);
  err = pthread_create(&child[i], NULL, test, (void *)&i);
  if(err) {
   printf("Can't create thread %d\n", i);
   return 0;
  }
 }
 for(i = 0; i < THREAD_NUM; i++) {
  printf("Join thread %d\n", i);
  err = pthread_join(child[i], &reStr);
  if(err) {
   printf("Can't join thread %d\n", i);
   return 0;
  }
  else{
    printf("Returned string at %s\n", (char*)reStr);
  }
 }
 printf("Main Function\n");  
 return 0; 
}
```

After compiling the program, we obtain the result as follows:

Creating thread 0 at 0xbf99f628

Creating thread 1 at 0xbf99f628

Join thread 0

the value of num: 0 at 0xbf99f628

the value of num: 0 at 0xbf99f628

Returned string at exit

Join thread 1

Returned string at exit

Main Function

I don't know why I get the value of num is 0 for both child threads.
In my opinion, I should get the value 1 for at least one child thread because I have set the value to 1 in the father thread.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2kqI.jpg)

Comment: There are no closures in C, you only have a single stack variable `i` here, and you set it back to `0` at the beginning of the next loop.

Answer (score 1):

i is again being set to 0 during initialization of 2nd for loop, after creating both threads. 
Use some other variable(int j) for looping 2nd time.

Comment: Thanks very much, I see

Answer (score 0):

```
pthread_create(&child[i], NULL, test, (void *)&i);
```

Each and every one of your threads is receiving the address of the same `i` that your loop modifies. Since the order of execution for threads is unspecified, there is no telling *when* each thread will read that `i` here:

```
int num = *(int*)args;
```

It could happen immediately, or after you finish the first loop and reset `i` to zero in the second one, thus both threads see 0.

If you want each thread to read its own unique value, you need to make sure they each point at a different piece of data. You can accomplish it with the following slight change:

```
pthread_t child[THREAD_NUM];
int       child_data[THREAD_NUM];
...
  child_data[i] = i;
  err = pthread_create(&child[i], NULL, test, &child_data[i]);
```